# Python--cosine similarity within images for image segmentation, is it useful?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-segmentation, cosine-similarity

|These are galaxy images this program produces, 
 all you have to do is change the image path|These are the images that this program produces|
|-|-|
|[image]|[image]|
I had an idea to perform cosine similarity within an image, with 2 for loops. It's kind of slow but it seems to outline everything pretty well, from bowls of soup to galaxies, airplanes and text. My question is, I can't think of a use for image segmentation, especially of this kind, so I was wondering, what is image segmentation useful for? I don't really know how to utilize it in any way. Please let me know if the code looks messed up this is my first time posting on here. Also, how would I make it faster but still effective?

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import numpy as np
import cv2

def compute_cosine_similarity(x, y):
    x = np.array(x).reshape(1, -1)
    y = np.array(y).reshape(1, -1)
    return cosine_similarity(x, y)

file_path = './natural_images/airplane/airplane_0019.jpg' # natural_images -- kaggle dataset

image = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

original_image = cv2.imread(file_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

image_shapes = np.array(image).shape
image_normalized = (np.array(image).reshape\
    (image_shapes[0], image_shapes[1], 3) - 127.5) / 127.5

mask = np.zeros((image_shapes[0], image_shapes[1], 1))

for i in range(0, image_shapes[0] - 16, 4):
    for j in range(0, image_shapes[1] - 16, 4):
        if compute_cosine_similarity(image_normalized[i : i + 8, j : j + 8], \
            image_normalized[i + 8 : i + 16, j + 8 : j + 16]) < 0.75:
            image[i : i + 4, j : j + 4] = (0, 0, 0)
            mask[i : i + 4, j : j + 4] = 1.0

cv2.imshow('Original Image', original_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow('Image with Mask', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imshow('Mask', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: can you post the input image and the resulting ones?

Comment: @cripcate I have added one example.

Comment: I added another example but I seem to have not separated them very well. I am sorry I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I made an edit because for some reason the 'cosine similarity' imported from scikit-learn wasn't showing up.